# Перемещение скроллбара к последнему виджету

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно чтобы ползунок скроллбара всегда был внизу. То есть показывались последние добавленные виджеты, а старые уходили наверх. 
Порылся в Qt документации и попытался сделать так, добавив это в конец функции `create_label`, но ничего не изменилось:

```
a = self.scrollarea.viewportSizeHint()
self.scrollarea.scrollContentsBy(a.width(), a.height())
```

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.vvbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.label_box = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton('button')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.create_label)

        self.area.setLayout(self.label_box)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)
        self.vvbox.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.vvbox.addWidget(self.button)

    def create_label(self):
        label = QLabel('text')
        self.label_box.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А попробуйте так ([ссылка на источник](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32852-How-can-I-always-keep-the-scroll-bar-at-the-bottom-of-a-QScrollArea?p=152817#post152817)):

```
def init_ui(self):
    ...
    scrollbar = self.scrollarea.verticalScrollBar()
    scrollbar.rangeChanged.connect(lambda min, max: scrollbar.setValue(max))
    ...

def create_label(self):
    label = QLabel('text')
    self.label_box.addWidget(label)
    self.scrollarea.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(self.scrollarea.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

Comment: Как и у автора вопроса в источнике, возникла проблема того, что скроллбар останавливается на предпоследнем элементе. Он решил её с помощью сигналов\слотов, с которыми я пока не сильно знаком, поэтому я немного затрудняюсь перевести его C(насколько я понял) код в питоновский.

Comment: @type49, действительно... стоило добавить добавление номера в `label` и заметил это :) Обновил ответ

Comment: Да, всё работает. А можно небольшой комментарий, как именно работает эта labmda функция?

Comment: Аналогично методу `moveScrollBarToBottom` из [комментария](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32852-How-can-I-always-keep-the-scroll-bar-at-the-bottom-of-a-QScrollArea?p=152861#post152861) -- на сигнал `rangeChanged` вызываем лямбду и сдвигаем ползунок `scrollbar` на значение `max`